# Many to many query with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables: `WAS`, `USER` and connection table `WAS_USER`. The thing I would like to achieve is to get all the rows from table `WAS` and if there are many users to the same `WAS` I would like to have one row for each one.
for example:

```
WAS:
    id | name
    1  | 'was1'
    2  | 'was2'

USER:
    id | name
    1  | 'user1'
    2  | 'user2'

WAS_USER:
    userId | wasId
    1      | 1
    2      | 1
```

So after queering I need to get this:

```
wasrId | userId | wasName | userName
1      | 1      | 'was1'  | 'user1'
1      | 2      | 'was1'  | 'user2'
1      | 2      | 'was1'  | 'user2'
```

Ordinary join between the 3 tables will give my only rows from `WAS`, what I need is some kind of `left join` on 3 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what worked for me:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM WAS W LEFT JOIN WAS_USER WU ON W.id=WU.wasID) TMP LEFT JOIN USER U ON TMP.userId=U.userId
```

Don't know about the efficiency though...